# How to move repeated column data into rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

How do I rewrite the data from col3 from the table below so:

```
col1    col2    col3    
1       1       5    
1       2       3    
1       2       4    
1       2       4    
1       2       6    
1       1       5    
1       2       7    
1       3       7
```

becomes

```
col1     col2   col3    col4    col5    col6    col7    colN
1       1       5       5
1       2       3       4       4       6       7
1       3       7
```

Comment: If you don't know how many columns are in the result set, then you need to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you put the results into an *array* rather than in separate columns.  In order to put the data in separate columns, you will need some type of dynamic SQL.

So, perhaps this meets your needs:

```
select col1, col2, array_agg(col3 order by col3)
from t
group by col1, col2;
```

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed maximum number of columns, you can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select
    col1,
    col2,
    max(col3) filter(where rn = 1) col3,
    max(col3) filter(where rn = 2) col4,
    max(col3) filter(where rn = 3) col5,
    max(col3) filter(where rn = 4) col6,
    max(col3) filter(where rn = 5) col7
from (
    select
        col1,
        col2,
        row_number() over(partition by col1, col2 order by col3) rn
    from mytable
) t
```